# How to add grid lines in SAS

Tags: sas

I have a times series that I plot using proc gplot. Is there an easy way to add custom grid lines? The reason for doing so is I want to make it easier to distinguish between quarters. M x-axis has dates such as 01/01/13 and I want to add gridlines to the x axis at particular dates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of any specific 'custom gridline' option, but I can think of a couple of ways you could do this:

- Plot an additional series for each gridline - clutters up the legend (if you have one), but it's relatively simple to get things to line up in the right place.
- Use an annotation dataset to draw gridlines on the plot area. This won't clutter up the legend, but you would need to explicitly calculate the plot co-ordinates where you want to draw your gridlines, which would be rather laborious.
- Define your x-axis major tickmarks so that they fall at quarter boundary points and use the grid option on your plot statement. Provided that your axis is the right length, and you define the right number of major tickmarks, this should give you your gridlines where you want them. I think this is probably the best option overall, unless someone else has a better idea.